# Implemented a View like Iphone standard address View

Tags: iphone, email, user-interface, email-client

Is there anyway to implement a view like iphone address view in email compose screen.

I have tried standard UIView which holds a couple of UILabelView, when User touch it, I will change UILabelView to UIButtonView followed by a UITextFieldView, 
however, it does not work exactly as Iphone standard address input view and plus I can not detect [back space] when UITextField is empty.

Any good ideas?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

1: Include the `Addressbook.framework` and `AddressbookUI.framework` to your project.

2: in your custom `UIViewController`, have it inherit from `ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate` to respond to the events.

3: Call setupAddressbookView to initialize the process.

4: Let the user do the rest

```
-(void) setupAddressbookView 
{
     ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *controller = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
     controller.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
     controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
     [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
     [controller release];
}

-(BOOL) peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    // show your mail view here
    return NO;
}

-(void) peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is what Jeff is looking to achieve. It sounds like Jeff wants a control that resembles the `To:` field in the email compose screen where one enters a name or email address the text is tokenised.

Comment: Jasarien answer is right, and Richadrd'answer is also a great idea, since I will try it anyway.

Comment: implement it by everything customized.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider having a look at the [Three20 library](http://three20.info).

It contains a control that resembles the Email compose view, including the `To:` field with the tokenised names/addresses.

You could either use it, or look at the source to help you write your own.

Comment: Thanks, Jasarien, I will try the website you recommend,